# VBA Vlookup date in number format

Tags: excel, vba, date, format, vlookup

hope I can count on your support with this issue i've been facing for sometime:

I Have a Userform that vlookups Dates in one tab and returns it into a textbox inside the userform.The problem is that the format is as number not date, even though in the worksheet everything it's completely fine with the format as date.

The dates within the sheet also comes from another userform that inputs the data.

```
Sub date()
Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = Worksheets("NEWIPS").Range("B:P")

'VLookups
prodstart.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ModelCombo, MyRange, 11, False)

releasedate.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ModelCombo, MyRange, 13, False)
```

Comment: If column A in Country is a true date then `ModelCombo & Label16` is creating a string.  Vlookup want an exact match.  A string that looks like a date is not a date and will not match with one.

Comment: Sorry Scott, you are totally right... I've updated the wrong part of my code (Sorry!). Now i've got the right one. Could you please give me any advices on why this is happening? On this vlookup there's not even a string. :(